# JodaTime time from until without date

Tags: jodatime

Is there any JodaTime type to represent only time without date. I will store opening times of companies, e.g.:

> 08:00 - 12:00 and 14:00 - 16:00 on monday
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

[org.joda.time.LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) is such a type representing time without date. You could create your own interval class consisting of start time and end time.

Then you will be able to map any day of week (in Joda-Time only available as an integer in range 1-7 = mon-sun) to a list of clock intervals (usually sorted by start time).

---

About conversion between `LocalTime` and `DateTime`:

[LocalTime => DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTime-org.joda.time.LocalTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-)

```
LocalTime time = ...;

LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2015, 12, 14);
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
DateTime dt = date.toDateTime(time, zone);
```

[DateTime => LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalTime--) (using the timezone stored in `DateTime`)

```
DateTime dt = ...;
LocalTime lt = dt.toLocalTime();
```

Note, Joda-Time takes into account daylight switching during these conversions and applies a strict strategy (conversion will fail for invalid local times but opening times of enterprises should be always valid).

Comment: I have created my own class but with two DateTimes and I use a formatter to only get the time. Is this approach ok from your point of view? I am also a little bitt confused what **Local** means. Does this time change during switch from summer- to winter time?

Comment: @user3318489 I prefer `LocalTime` because it exactly models what you have as input. Consider `LocalTime.parse("08:00")`. In contrast, `DateTime` is rather like an instant with a connection to a timezone which is just blow-up AND is sensitive for daylight switching effects (which you surely don't want). The term "Local" is misleading for many people however. In Joda terminology this does not mean connection to local timezone but no timezone instead.

Comment: My application is mainly based on DateTime types and I am really unsure what happens at daylight switching. So would you prefere **LocalTime** all over the application ? Thanks!

Comment: @user3318489 `LocalTime` ignores daylight switching and just literally models what you have as clock time input. If other parts of your app require `DateTime`? Well, I don't know your app but if necessary then you can easily change every `LocalTime` to a `DateTime` by specifying a calendar date and a timezone. See also my update for conversion examples.